# how to remove 10px from an absolute height in CSS

Tags: css, html

I have an issue where I can't figure out how to make these "piano keys" move up 10px.
I am building a piano app and the code I have so far is at this JSFiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/Klauss/fxhd5z3e/#&togetherjs=RmEh5FeuIE"
     ``

but what I want to do is move the black keys up by ten pixels. I have tried:

`margin-top: 10px;`
    `top: 10px;`
    `top: -10px;`
    `margin-top: -10px;`

if someone could please help me, that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add the `margin-top: -10px` after the more general `margin: 1px` to not override it:

```
.blackKey {
  /* ... */
  margin: 1px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

This could be [combined](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/margin#Values) to `margin: -10px 1px 1px 1px` or `margin: -10px 1px 1px`.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxhd5z3e/1/).

Comment: Thanks. This is just what I am looking for, what's weird us that from experience, CSS isn't order-specific. I was able to apply left / right properties before the position.

Comment: The same property will always override a previous declaration of it. In this case `margin: 1px` is just shorthand for the four declarations `margin-top: 1px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; margin-left: 1px` and will always override previous margin values, i.e. for `margin-top`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `margin-top` of `-10px` to `.blackkey` class as below, by keeping other sides as 1px and just changing top value.

```
.blackKey {
    background: #232323;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    height: 20px;
    color: #eee;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: -10px 1px 1px 1px; /*Add this*/
}
```

```css
#keyboard {
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 background: black;
 height: 100%;
}
.whiteKey {
 background: #FCFBE3;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 1px;
 height:30px;
 text-align: right;
}
.blackKey {
 background: #232323;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 75%;
 height: 20px;
 color: #eee;
 z-index: 10;
 margin: -10px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="keyboard">
 <span class="whiteKey">C</span>
 <span class="blackKey">C#</span>
 <span class="whiteKey">D</span>
 <span class="blackKey">D#</span>
 <span class="whiteKey">E</span>
 <span class="whiteKey">F</span>
 <span class="blackKey">F#</span>
 <span class="whiteKey">G</span>
 <span class="blackKey">G#</span>
 <span class="whiteKey">A</span>
 <span class="blackKey">A#</span>
 <span class="whiteKey">B</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the fiddle: use after as it's easier to control:

```css
#keyboard {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.whiteKey {
  background: #FCFBE3;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1px;
  height:30px;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
.withBlack:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  background: #232323;
  width: 75%;
  height: 20px;
  color: #eee;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: left;
}
.keyC:after {
  content: "C#";
}
.keyD:after {
  content: "D#";
}
.keyF:after {
  content: "F#";
}
.keyG:after {
  content: "G#";
}
.keyA:after {
  content: "A#";
}
```

```html
<div id="keyboard">
  <div class="whiteKey withBlack keyC">C</div>
  <div class="whiteKey withBlack keyD">D</div>
  <div class="whiteKey">E</div>
  <div class="whiteKey withBlack keyF">F</div>
  <div class="whiteKey withBlack keyG">G</div>
  <div class="whiteKey withBlack keyA">A</div>
  <div class="whiteKey">B</div>
</div>
```